# in Tic-tac-toe on an NxN board, what is the minimum goal (number in a row) that guarantees a tie?

Tags: computer-ai, combinatorial-game-theory, tic-tac-toe

I've been working on a Tic-Tac-Toe AI (Minimax with AB pruning).

As far as I can tell, for an NxN board, player 1 can always win if the goal is to get less than N-1 in a row (for N > 4). Is there a known bound for the number in a row or the size of the board?

Comment: This generalization of Tic-Tac-Toe is called m,n,k-game.  (getting k in a row on a (m,n) board). See wikipedia for some known results - 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M,n,k-game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This generalization of Tic-Tac-Toe is called **m,n,k-game**. (the goal is to get **k** in a row on a **(m,n)** board).

Some known bounds: (source [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M,n,k-game))

- (5,5,4) is a draw.
- (6,6,5) is a draw.
- (7,7,5) and (8,8,5) are draws.
- (15,15,5) is a win.
- (9,6,6) and (7,7,6) are both draws via pairings.

When the goal is 9 or larger (k>=9) the second player can force a draw:

> When k = 9 and the board is infinite, the second
>   player can draw via a "pairing strategy". A draw on an infinite board
>   means that the game will go on forever with perfect play. A pairing
>   strategy involves dividing all the squares of the board into pairs in
>   such a way that by always playing on the pair of the first player's
>   square, the second player is ensured that the first player cannot get
>   k in a line. A pairing strategy on an infinite board can be applied to
>   any finite board as well - if the strategy calls for making a move
>   outside the board, then the second player makes an arbitrary move
>   inside the board.